# How did Bob Taylor get out of the children's room?

Tags: plot-explanation, prisoners

I watched the scene in *Prisoners* where Bob Taylor supposedly breaks into the Dovers' house carefully. When he gets into the children's room, Mrs. Dover comes right after him but then he mysteriously leaves the house through the bedroom window. How did he get out? It just isn't possible.

Comment: Why isn't it possible? The camera cuts away for several moments and when it returns the window is open and he is gone. Its not very high up for him to climb through and jump down and later on Detective Loki finds the other sock the he stole from the room outside the window on the ground, suggesting that Bob Taylor dropped it there when using it as an escape route.

Comment: @sanpaco In order for him to get out of the children's room and finally leave the house through the bedroom window, he would have to pass by Mrs. Dover who was in the hallway the whole time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We see him enter Anna's room at which point Mrs. Dover is awoken by a noise. The camera pans to her for approximately 20 seconds before she gets up and goes to investigate, more than enough time for him to grab some clothing and leave Anna's room and hide somewhere.

There are two other doors in the hallway in between Anna's room and the master bedroom, a bathroom and probably a closet. **He hides in the bathroom and waits for Mrs Dover to run into Anna's room, and then leaves via the master bedroom window.** We can even see that the bathroom door which was closed at first is later opened.

**Bathroom is closed**
[image]

**Bathroom is open**
[image]

Comment: Wow, this is just genius. Thanks, man. I thought I'd never get answers to my questions